# How to set the default value for the not null column based on the column datatype?

Tags: c#, sql

It's possible to assign the default value for the not null column based on the datatype of the column.

Ex:

```
ALTER TABLE Address ADD City char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA'
```

In this city column is char so I assign some char value('na') as default value.

Suppose dynamically or runtime only I know the datatype(int,image,char,bit) of the column in such case how can I give the default value.

Is there any alternative way to add default value based on the datatype?

Comment: Isn't it better to just keep "unknown" as null instead of magic values? As a bonus, null works for pretty much every data type.

Comment: @Siva, Where (in c# code?) and when (filling datagridview or etc) do you want to do?

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework? Why did you use the C# tag?

Comment: There are no special default values per datatype in SQL.

Comment: Have a think why you want to do this. Keeping the column as null will make more sense in most cases.